# Inventory balance from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in SQL Server, the first one for inventory and second for inventory movement. I need a query to show the remaining raw material for each serial number and if there's a movement or not.

Table 1

```
+----------+------------+-----+
| CodeRaw  | Serial_Raw | Qty |
+----------+------------+-----+
|        1 |          1 | 100 |
|        1 |          2 | 150 |
|        2 |          1 |  80 |
|        1 |          3 | 100 |
|        1 |          4 | 100 |
+----------+------------+-----+
```

And Table 2

```
+------------+----------+------------+----------+--+
| CodeBatch  | CodeRaw  | Serial_Raw | Qty_Added|  |
+------------+----------+------------+----------+--+
|          1 |        1 |          1 |       80 |  |
|          2 |        1 |          1 |       10 |  |
|          3 |        1 |          2 |      150 |  |
|          4 |        1 |          3 |       80 |  |
+------------+----------+------------+----------+--+
```

I've already tried some code but I just got results where there is an inventory movenent, not showing all QT for a specific raw (Code_Raw).

Probably I'm missing something....

This is the query I have

```
declare @tbl1 table (CodeRaw INT, Serial_Raw INT, Qty INT)
declare @tbl2 table (CodeBatch INT, CodeRaw INT, Serial_Raw INT, QtyAdded INT)

insert into @tbl1 values (1,1,100), (1,2,150), (2,1,80), (1,3,100),(1,4,100)
insert into @tbl2 values (1,1,1,80), (2,1,1,10), (3,1,2,150), (4,1,3,80)

  SELECT t2.Serial_Raw, t1.Qty - t2.QtyAdded AS Total_Remaining  FROM @tbl1 t1
        INNER JOIN (SELECT CodeRaw, Serial_Raw , SUM(QtyAdded) QtyAdded FROM @tbl2
                    GROUP BY CodeRaw, Serial_Raw) AS t2 ON t2.CodeRaw = t1.CodeRaw AND t1.Serial_Raw = t2.Serial_Raw
    WHERE t1.CodeRaw = 1
```

I expected

```
Serial_Raw  Total_Remaining 
----------  --------------- 
1           10  
2            0  
3           20 
4           100
```

But the result is

```
Serial_Raw  Total_Remaining 
----------  --------------- 
1           10  
2            0  
3           20
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is your `INNER JOIN`. It is only returning results for your inventory that's in both tables. Meaning, if an item has no inventory movement, the total count is not returned.

**Step 1:** Switch your `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. This will return all results in the inventory table (`tbl1`) even if it has no movement (`tbl2`). Also, select `Serial_Raw` from `tbl1` instead of `tbl2` in case of NULL value returned from `JOIN`.

**Step 2:** Step 1 will return `NULL` for the `tbl2.QtyAdded` in your `JOIN`. To account for this, you can do a NULL check in your calculation by using `ISNULL(tbl2.QtyAdded, 0)`. Then, if there is not `QtyAdded`, the `tbl1.Qty` will subtract 0 (stay the same).

**Resulting Code:**

```
declare @tbl1 table (CodeRaw INT, Serial_Raw INT, Qty INT)
declare @tbl2 table (CodeBatch INT, CodeRaw INT, Serial_Raw INT, QtyAdded INT)

insert into @tbl1 values (1,1,100), (1,2,150), (2,1,80), (1,3,100),(1,4,100)
insert into @tbl2 values (1,1,1,80), (2,1,1,10), (3,1,2,150), (4,1,3,80)

  SELECT t1.Serial_Raw, t1.Qty - ISNULL(t2.QtyAdded, 0) AS Total_Remaining  FROM @tbl1 t1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT CodeRaw, Serial_Raw , SUM(QtyAdded) QtyAdded FROM @tbl2
                    GROUP BY CodeRaw, Serial_Raw) AS t2 ON t2.CodeRaw = t1.CodeRaw 
                         AND t1.Serial_Raw = t2.Serial_Raw
    WHERE t1.CodeRaw = 1
```

**Results:**

```
Serial_Raw  Total_Remaining
-----------------------------
1           10
2           0
3           20
4           100
```

Answer (score 1):

Use LEFT OUTER JOIN instead INNER JOIN, also ISNULL and serial_Raw from left table.

```
declare @tbl1 table (CodeRaw INT, Serial_Raw INT, Qty INT)
declare @tbl2 table (CodeBatch INT, CodeRaw INT, Serial_Raw INT, QtyAdded INT)

insert into @tbl1 values (1,1,100), (1,2,150), (2,1,80), (1,3,100),(1,4,100)
insert into @tbl2 values (1,1,1,80), (2,1,1,10), (3,1,2,150), (4,1,3,80)

  SELECT t1.Serial_Raw, t1.Qty - ISNULL(t2.QtyAdded,0) AS Total_Remaining  FROM @tbl1 t1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT CodeRaw, Serial_Raw , SUM(QtyAdded) QtyAdded FROM @tbl2
                    GROUP BY CodeRaw, Serial_Raw) AS t2 

                    ON t2.CodeRaw = t1.CodeRaw AND t1.Serial_Raw = t2.Serial_Raw
    WHERE t1.CodeRaw = 1
```

Result:

```
Serial_Raw  Total_Remaining
----------- ---------------
1           10
2           0
3           20
4           100
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do 2 changes

1. Left join to the second table.
2. Check the second table's column is null, then set to 0 for minus

```
    SELECT t1.Serial_Raw, t1.Qty - isnull(t2.QtyAdded, 0) AS Total_Remaining
      FROM @tbl1 t1
    Left Join 
   (SELECT CodeRaw, Serial_Raw, SUM(QtyAdded) QtyAdded FROM @tbl2 GROUP BY CodeRaw, Serial_Raw) 
    AS t2 ON t2.CodeRaw = t1.CodeRaw AND t1.Serial_Raw = t2.Serial_Raw
    Where t1.CodeRaw = 1
```